# converting a docker mysql volume from container to shared directory

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to change an existing docker mysql volume that contains my databases in a container from:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_data
```

to a shared volume, eg

```
/mysql_data
```

but when I change the `docker-compose.yml` volume parameter from:

```
- data:/var/lib/mysql
```

to

```
- /mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I lose all my database files and mysql starts as vanilla install.

How can I move or otherwise change the existing container mysql storage to the shared storage?

Comment: i should say that my solution was to back up the database within docker using a docker exec command to a shared directory and then import the backup via mysql workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a container that has both mounts, you can copy data from one place to the other.

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \                 # don't keep this container after exit
  -v docker_data:/old \  # mount the old directory
  -v /mysql_data:/new \  # mount the new directory
  -w /old \              # cd /old
  busybox \              # image to run
  cp -a . /new           # command to run
```

For the most part you need to actually be inside a Docker container to access Docker volumes.  The Docker documentation's discussion on [backing up and restoring volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) also uses this technique.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a data volume container which is pretty straightforward.

```
$ docker create -v /var/lib/mysql --name mysqldata mysql
```

Next, you need to mount the data volume container "mysqldata" when you run the MySQL container which will have MySQL running.

```
$ docker run --name mysqldb --volumes-from mysqldata -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3307:3306 mysql
```

To quick test add few data and delete your existing container and rerun new one. you will see your data are persistent .

Same equivalent command you can use in your yaml file.